# Having Problems Plotting a 3D Map in R

Tags: r, 3d, plotly.js

I am having problems plotting a 3D map in Rstudio.

Here is the code I used;

```
plot_ly(myLocalClean, x = ~date, y = ~median, z = ~sales, opacity=0.5) #3D
```

**my result**

*No trace type specified:
Based on info supplied, a 'scatter3d' trace seems appropriate.
Read more about this trace type -> https://plotly.com/r/reference/#scatter3d
No scatter3d mode specifed:
Setting the mode to markers
Read more about this attribute -> https://plotly.com/r/reference/#scatter-mode*

On the **viewer tab**, there is no result for the plot_ly. I get the error **WebGL is not supported by your browser- visit  https://get.webgl.org  for more info**

I tried to enable the webGL but I still get the same error.

Please I need your input.

Comment: Could you please share your data using `dput(df)`?

Comment: > txhousing
# A tibble: 8,602 x 9
   city     year month sales   volume median listings inventory  date
   <chr>   <int> <int> <dbl>    <dbl>  <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl> <dbl>
 1 Abilene  2000     1    72  5380000  71400      701       6.3 2000 
 2 Abilene  2000     2    98  6505000  58700      746       6.6 2000.
 3 Abilene  2000     3   130  9285000  58100      784       6.8 2000.
 4 Abilene  2000     4    98  9730000  68600      785       6.9 2000.
 5 Abilene  2000     5   141 10590000  67300      794       6.8 2000.

Comment: @Quinten, I used the built-in data set txhousing

Answer (score 0):

If you run the following code, the errors are away:

```
library(plotly)
fig <- plot_ly(txhousing, x = ~date, y = ~median, z = ~sales)
fig <- fig %>% add_markers()
fig <- fig %>% layout(scene = list(xaxis = list(title = 'date'),
                                   yaxis = list(title = 'median'),
                                   zaxis = list(title = 'sales')))

fig
```

Output:

[image]

The problem is that your data has a lot of missing values:

```
> sapply(txhousing, function(x) sum(is.na(x)))
     city      year     month     sales    volume    median  listings inventory      date 
        0         0         0       568       568       616      1424      1467         0
```

That is way you get the warning message.

Comment: Thank  you so  much.  The codes worked but  I'm still having issues viewing the map as  I  get the error WebGL not supported.  So I am guessing  it's from my browser.